# CVXPY with MOSEK solver: how do I find the constraints corresponding to the Mosek "index"?

Tags: optimization, cvxpy, mosek

I am solving an SDP in cvxpy with MOSEK as a solver.
My problem is infeasible, and MOSEK has the nice feature that it provides an "Infeasibility Report". In my case, the report looks like this:

```
MOSEK PRIMAL INFEASIBILITY REPORT.
Problem status: The problem is primal infeasible
The following constraints are involved in the primal infeasibility.
Index    Name             Lower bound      Upper bound      Dual lower       Dual upper      
37                        none             -0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00     2.647059e-03    
406                       none             3.000000e+02     0.000000e+00     6.250000e-04    
2364                      none             -0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00     6.183824e-03    
2980                      none             -8.100000e-01    0.000000e+00     1.000000e+00    
3049                      -0.000000e+00    -0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00     4.235294e+00    
3052                      -0.000000e+00    -0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00     1.000000e+00
```

I would like to find out which constrains this report is referring to. My constraint list in cvxpy only contains 105 constraints, but many of those are matrix or vector constraints. This explains why the index reported by MOSEK are up to 3052. However, it makes it hard to find out which of my constraints are listed in the report.

Is there a way to find out which of my cvxpy constraints are reported by MOSEK?

Comment: It might be most productive to relax your constraints with slacks, minimize the sum of slacks and see what is nonzero.

Comment: that is a good idea, I will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Mosek via its Cvxpy Interface and facing the same issue.

My hypothesis is **ordering of constraint Mosek's Infeasibility Report is exactly same as in Cvxpy** because:

1. I had tested it on 2 sample infeasible problems (i.e. knew aprior as to which constraint are causing infeasibility) and found the hypothesis holds.
2. I had taken a quick look at Cvxpy to Mosek conversion code in cvxpy codebase and found cvxpy doesn't change constraint ordering.

So, the conclusion is the hypothesis.

Please Note: The conclusion is based on quite small test set + naive understanding of cvxpy codebase, so there exists minor chances that it may be wrong.

Comment: It may depend heavily on what type of problem is being solved and what atoms are used and last but definitely not least whether cvxpy dualized or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! didn't knew that. So, can we say **the hypothesis holds mostly but not always**?